# React Native keyboard aware scrollview?

Tags: react-native, keyboard

I want to know how I can make a keyboard aware scrollview without using the [popular library](https://github.com/APSL/react-native-keyboard-aware-scroll-view), because that is currently [giving me a bug](https://github.com/APSL/react-native-keyboard-aware-scroll-view/issues/199) when using "controlled" TextInputs within the KeyboardAwareScrollView

Has anyone managed to pull this off? Perhaps with the KeyboardAvoidingView?
The solution has to work on both iOS and Android

Answer (score 1):

You can make use of `KeyboardAvoidingView` component. Import it from the 'react-native' along with all other components you need and keep your UI within that component.
for example,

```
import {KeyboardAvoidingView} from 'react-native'
export default class App extends React.Component{
    render(){
        return(
            <KeyboardAvoidingView  behavior="padding">
                Your UI
            </KeyboardAvoidingView>
);
}
}
```

Don't forget to add the prop `behaviour="padding"`. It worked for me on android device. I don't have an iPhone to test it, but hope it would work.
Take a loot at this [this link](https://github.com/facebook/react-native-website/blob/master/docs/keyboardavoidingview.md) for further information. Hope this helped.